# Entity framework starter kit on VS 2012

Tags: frameworks, entity

I have downloaded and installed the Entity Designer Starter Kit on both VS 2010 and 2012.  I've created a project and have customized that project to allow me to add (for now) three attributes for each field value:  See Below:  (I'd post the image but I've only started posting here and I don't have 10 points) :(

As you can't see above, the Extension is working...on VS 2010, however, we need to use VS 2012 - so we can have the new support for geography fields in our Model, but it doesn't seem to work in VS 2012. The extension shows up as an installed extension in the Extension Manager in both versions, but doesn't work (or do anything in 2012.) when we build a new Model or open an existing one.  :(

I've looked at the manifest for versioning info, and it DOES show up in the Extension Manager as having been installed (in both versions).  (See part of Manifest below -- We are using the Professional version of 2012)

```
<SupportedProducts>
  <VisualStudio Version="11.0">
    <Edition>VSTS</Edition>
    <Edition>VSTD</Edition>
    <Edition>Pro</Edition>
    <Edition>Express_All</Edition>
  </VisualStudio>
    <VisualStudio Version="10.0">
      <Edition>VSTS</Edition>
      <Edition>VSTD</Edition>
      <Edition>Pro</Edition>
      <Edition>Express_All</Edition>
    </VisualStudio>
</SupportedProducts>
```

Does anyone have any idea why its not running in 2012?

Thanks for any help!!!!!!!

bob

Answer (score 1):

Back in 2010 I found that the Starter Kit did not work, perhaps due to the version being for VS2010 RC.

So I rebuilt it, and today, I've just upgraded it to VS2012.
So you can get it from my Blog.

All I did was run it though the VS upgrade wizard, and then change the manifest to VS2012 and it worked fine. Perhaps you could explain a little more "geography fields", as I've not read up yet on any of the changes in VS2012.

http://www.jsrsoft.co.uk/blog/post/Entity-Framework-Starter-Kit-alternative